# Font size too small

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, extsizes

I am making a `pdf` worksheet that is intended to be viewed on the screen and also printed out.

I find that the default font size for `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` is too small. If I zoom in (say, to 150%) with a pdf reader, it is no longer comfortable to read because the width of the text takes up too much of the screen space (it requires eyes/head to move from left to right).

I considered increasing the left an right margins, but this would not be very efficient for those who will print it out (lots of wasted space).

I also considered increasing the font size with [extsizes](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes), but it says

> [Don't use `extsizes` just because ... you think the font looks too small on the screen](https://mirrors.sorengard.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf#section.1)

So my question is, **what should I do to increase readability when I think the font is too small?**

Comment: Would creating 2 different versions be a good idea? (One version for screen, one for paper-copy)

Comment: Change your screen  for a king-size model ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I'd be more than happy to... if I don't need to pay for it

Comment: If you are using `fit page` or `fit width`, you can change the paper height or width (respectively) to change the scale.